# mutate tibble for particular rows specified by a numbers

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Trying to find **`dplyr` canonical** way to `mutate` a `tibble` by row number.
I went through many Stack Overflow questions and GH issues, functions like `row_number`, `if_else`, `case_when`, but it is still not clear what is the proper way to achieve the following.

Minimal example: having a data.frame, I would like to update one of its columns to a particular value (here `NA`) for particular rows by providing row indices (here rows 2 and 4).
Column to update doesn't have to be parametrized, but only row numbers.
Below base R to achieve the following.

```r
DF = data.frame(x=5:1)
idx = c(2L, 4L)
DF[idx, "x"] = NA_integer_
DF
#   x
#1  5
#2 NA
#3  3
#4 NA
#5  1
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `DF %>% mutate(x = replace(x, idx, NA))`

Comment: `replace` is base R function, is it dplyr way then? there is also `if_else` alternative

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using a base R function inside a dplyr one—and I can't imagine there's any way to *not* use base R functions even if for some reason that was what you wanted to do

Comment: Also, a hacky option is `DF %>% mutate(x = 'is.na<'(x, idx))`

Comment: @camille it is not a matter of not using base R function in dplyr, but knowing the canonical way that dplyr suggests to achieve the following. As I highlighted in question.

Comment: What I'm saying is that there's nothing wrong with what @akrun suggests with `replace`, just because it's a base function it should still work. You could also use something like `mutate(x = ifelse(row_number() %in% idx, NA_integer_, x))` to replace x at just those row numbers

Comment: It does feel sometimes like there should be a `mutate_when` function, doesn't it? I don't know that there is one, though. @camille's `if_else` solution is precisely what I was going to recommend; I think it's as close as we're going to come to canonical.

Comment: @camille thanks, your `row_number()` approach looks tidyverse-like. If I would go with R way I would chose simply `TB=as_tibble(DF); TB[idx, "x"] = NA_integer_`

Comment: Whoa @akrun! I need an open-mouthed GIF here. That's amazing! I totally learned something new here, and thank you, sincerely. I've amended my comment since it was still inside the 5-minute window. I would definitely recommend the base-R solution then, and I reckon the folks at RStudio / Tidyverse would too!

Comment: @akrun, `DF %>% mutate(x = 'is.na<'(x, idx))` throws "Evaluation error: could not find function "is.na<"", could you check?

Comment: @Artem  I use backquotes, but here for comments, i did a single quote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @camille feedback and the consent by other commentors the most tidyverse-like code is `mutate(x = ifelse(row_number() %in% idx, NA_integer_, x))`.

BTW. It is better to use `<-` instead of `=` assignments, and avoid usage capital letters in the names of objects. For more information please see [The tidyverse style guide](https://style.tidyverse.org/index.html)

So the full code:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x = 5:1)
idx <- c(2L, 4L)
df %>% mutate(x = ifelse(row_number() %in% idx, NA_integer_, x))

#   x
#1  5
#2 NA
#3  3
#4 NA
#5  1
```

Comment: `<-` vs `=` is a subject of style preference, neither is better. Actually `<-` has the disadvantage where a plain space changes the meaning from assignment operator to less than unary minus, for more details on that see: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3590#issuecomment-495776200

Comment: Although you answer is the most tidyverse way to achieve what I asked in the question, I don't think it should be recommended. Base R way works on tibbles also, and IMO it should be preferred. Accepting the answer as the question was about tidyverse way. It adds extra memory overhead as presented in my recent slides, thus has bigger memory requirements than base R way: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/talks/PAZUR_2019_why-data.table.pdf